# Can someone please explain why this C function is returning the value of 10?

Tags: c, function, return

Beginner question on C function here so please bear with me...

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
int some_function(void);

int result;
result = some_function();
printf("%d", result);

return 0;
}

int some_function(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // printf("%d", i);
    }

    return (i);    
}
```

I commented out the result of running the for loop which is all integers from 0 to 9.

I can not clearly understand why the final result of local int i is increased once more to finally provide a return of 10 out of int some_function(void).

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` That increments `i` until it gets to 10. So when the loop ends, `i` is 10 and that is what is returned.

Comment: OT: `return` is not a function call... The parentheses are unnecessary; harmless but unnecessary...

Comment: but the loop is meant to stop at 9 as i < 10 not <= 10, why does it increase one more time to generate a final return value of 10?

Comment: No, it says keep running whilst `i` is less than 10. It can't fail the test and exit the loop until `i` gets to 10. So when the loop terminates by definition `i` is no longer less than 10 and is in fact 10 in this case.

Comment: @AMW The loop stops when the condition is false. When i == 9 (or less), the condition is true. When i == 10, the condition is false and the loop terminates...

Answer (score 3):

`for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` says:

1. Initialize `i` to zero.
2. Test whether `i < 10` is true. If it is, execute the body of the loop. If it is not, exit the loop.
3. Increment `i` and go to step 2.

Therefore, the loop continues executing until `i < 10` is **false**.

When `i` is nine, `i < 10` is true, and the loop does not exit. When `i` is ten, then `i < 10` is false, and the loop exits.

Therefore, when the loop exits, `i` is ten.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
i = 0
while (i < 10) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

When `i` is 9, the loop body is executed, then `i` is incremented (and its value is now 10), then the test of the while loop is executed once more, and the loop exits, with `i` still having the value 10.